# Establishing relationship between two variables with low sample size(5)

Tags: regression, linear-model, linear

My question is -  Is elevation range of plants linked to intraspecific trait variability. I want to explore the relationship between the coefficient of variance (CV) of a certain plant functional trait (dependent variable) and the associated elevation range (independent variable). Ideally I would have run an linear regression, however my sample size is only 5 since I  have this data for only 5 species. Hence I only have 5 CVs along with the associated elevational ranges. IS there any other way I can test for this?

Comment: Can you include a scatterplot of the data ? Why do you only have 5 ? The usual approach is to plan the study and do a power analysis, where you do a simple calculation based on the effect size you want to detect, which then tells you how many observations you need.  It's hard to understand why you would have a sample size of 5.

Comment: I have only collected data for 5 different species and hence the sample size is 5. Since I am trying to see the relationship between trait variation and range of occurrence of species I only have 5 CVs and the elevation range of the associated species.

Comment: However to estimate the CV I have functional trait values as a continuous variable along with the elevation of individuals from which these values were obtained. This data is there for 5 species.

Comment: What is "CV" ? And please add a scatterplot to your question.  So just to be clear - the 5 refers to the number of species ? And did you take measurements of individual plants within each species ? Or do you have only 5 data points in total ?

Comment: CV- Coefficient of variance. Yes, I have data for only 5 species. Yes I have measurements for individual plants within each species. Using the values of individuals within these 5 species I have estimated the Coefficient of variance for these each of these species. Just like how each indvidual has a functional trait value, eahc individual also has an associated value for elevation. I know the elevational range for each species by subtracting minimum elevation of occurence from the  maximum elevation of occurrence.